# Remove defined illegal characters from string

Tags: javascript, regex

The chracters match if they are back to back. If the defined illegal characters are part of a long string, the correct sanitized text is not returned. The illegal characters that I want to find and replace with empty space is '-_+=[]{}\|'

I have read various regex blogs, Mozilla Developer Network site, as well as some answers here in stackoverflow. I have used \ for +, [, and |. If there is a more simple way, please, share it.

```
function dirtyString(str) {
    cleanString = str.replace(/-_\+=\[]{}\|/g, "");
    return cleanString;
}
```

For most of sample codes I have run, I don't get anything returned. I have run on Codepen and jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your characters into a [character class](https://javascript.info/regexp-character-classes) (inside brackets)

A character class will math every character in it. For example, the regex `/[abc]/g` would match all of the a's, b's, and c's (the character class is `[abc]`. Also, the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9]` (which you might see a lot) matches all alphanumeric characters

Use a `/` before the brackets (`[]`). See more [here](https://javascript.info/regexp-escaping).

```js
var string = "s[s ass'-sas_+as[aasd]{ss}\asddfa|a]fasdf";

string = string.replace(/[ '-_+=\[\]{}\|]/g, '');
console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your characters into a regex character class:

```js
function dirtyString(str) {
    cleanString = str.replace(/[\-_+=\[\]{}\\|]/g, "");
    return cleanString;
}

var str = "HELLO-_+=[]{}|WORLD";
console.log(str);
console.log(dirtyString(str));
```

Note: You should escape square brackets and backslash even if inside a regex character class (not always true in every flavor of regex though).

Answer (score 0):

You need to select them via a character class (`[]`);

```js
function dirtyString(str) {
  cleanString = str.replace(/[\-_+=\[\]{}\\|]/g, "");
  return cleanString;
}

var string = "This -str_+in=g[ ]is {d}i|rty.";
console.log(dirtyString(string));
```